# Examples for string find in Python

Tags: python, string, find

I am trying to find some examples but no luck. Does anyone know of some examples on the net? I would like to know what it returns when it can't find, and how to specify from start to end, which I guess is going to be 0, -1.

Comment: Are you asking about http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#id4 ?  Are you asking about the find method, specifically?  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: Thanks yeah just the find method. I found that page but no examples.

Comment: It says -1 on the page.  What more did you need to know?

Comment: No I mean, just some examples.

Comment: Here you can find a discussion on its return value (`-1`) while unable to locate a substring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674764/examples-for-string-find-in-python

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you can use [`str.index`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.index) too:

```
>>> 'sdfasdf'.index('cc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#144>", line 1, in <module>
    'sdfasdf'.index('cc')
ValueError: substring not found
>>> 'sdfasdf'.index('df')
1
```

Comment: Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: it raises the error instead of returning a code, which is more pythonic, in my opinion.

Comment: exceptions should not be used for flow control. so, only use index() if no match would be abnormal.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden: using exception is perfectly pythonic. And certainly doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @aehlke in fact, in Python, using exceptions to control flow is usual and even recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092992/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java

Answer (score 113):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, do you mean [`find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)?

```
>>> x = "Hello World"
>>> x.find('World')
6
>>> x.find('Aloha');
-1
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you get, if it can't find?

Comment: Thanks, but why -1 here, not for index? I thought python prefers exceptions over special return values.

Comment: Thanks SilentGhost, I used your method.

Comment: find and index are the same functionality but with different results on no match. Python might in general prefer exceptions, but many users expect there to be a non-exception-raising-find-index method as well, especially as that's how it's done in almost every other language.

Comment: this works great for me - totally forgot that 0 result actually means a match!

Comment: can we use or here for ex-
x.find("Welcome" or  "welcome")

Answer (score 32):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> ```
> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if *sub* is not found.

So, some examples:

```
>>> my_str = 'abcdefioshgoihgs sijsiojs '
>>> my_str.find('a')
0
>>> my_str.find('g')
10
>>> my_str.find('s', 11)
15
>>> my_str.find('s', 15)
15
>>> my_str.find('s', 16)
17
>>> my_str.find('s', 11, 14)
-1
```

Answer (score 17):

Honestly, this is the sort of situation where I just open up Python on the command line and start messing around:

```
 >>> x = "Dana Larose is playing with find()"
 >>> x.find("Dana")
 0
 >>> x.find("ana")
 1
 >>> x.find("La")
 5
 >>> x.find("La", 6)
 -1
```

Python's interpreter makes this sort of experimentation easy.  (Same goes for other languages with a similar interpreter)

Comment: IPython makes this sort of thing even better.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search for the last instance of a string in a text, you can run rfind.

Example:

```
   s="Hello"
   print s.rfind('l')
```

output: 3

*no import needed

**Complete syntax:**

```
stringEx.rfind(substr, beg=0, end=len(stringEx))
```

Answer (score 2):

`find(      sub[, start[, end]])`

Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

From [the docs](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4.4/lib/string-methods.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
myString = 'abcabc'
myString.find('a')
```

This will give you the index!!!

Comment: Hi @Dave Brown, did you test your code? I think you'll find that it doesn't perform as indented because you made a typo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(file_dmp_path, 'rb') as file:
fsize = bsize = os.path.getsize(file_dmp_path)
word_len = len(SEARCH_WORD)
while True:
    p = file.read(bsize).find(SEARCH_WORD)
    if p > -1:
        pos_dec = file.tell() - (bsize - p)
        file.seek(pos_dec + word_len)
        bsize = fsize - file.tell()
    if file.tell() < fsize:
        seek = file.tell() - word_len + 1
        file.seek(seek)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

if x is a string and you search for y which also a string  their is two cases :
**case 1:** y is exist in x so  **x.find(y)** = the index (the position) of the y in x .
**case 2:** y is not exist so   **x.find (y)** = -1 this mean y is not found in x.