# How to determine whether a substring is in a different string

Tags: python, string

I have a sub-string:

```
substring = "please help me out"
```

I have another string:

```
string = "please help me out so that I could solve this"
```

How do I find if `substring` is a subset of `string` using Python?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

with `in`: `substring in string`:

```
>>> substring = "please help me out"
>>> string = "please help me out so that I could solve this"
>>> substring in string
True
```

Comment: gosh, python is too strong, I was think it needs a function to do it, but it is a build-in one O-o

Comment: I just actually was learning JS after learning Python, for this you would need to add loads of if else statements and other things. So, I just wanted to remind myself of how its done in Python, this answer made me say to myself 'Of course!', I mean things like this in Python are just so trivial you never give them much thought! :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Actually, to do the same in JS it's just `string.indexOf(substring) != -1`, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Once you find, yes substring exists in string, how do you find at what position is the string, and what happens if the substring is in the string more than once?

Comment: @yoshiserry if you want the position of `substring` in `string`, then you want yo use [string.index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/674775/162684)

Answer (score 21):

```
foo = "blahblahblah"
bar = "somethingblahblahblahmeep"
if foo in bar:
    # do something
```

(By the way - try to not name a variable `string`, since there's a Python standard library with the same name. You might confuse people if you do that in a large project, so avoiding collisions like that is a good habit to get into.)

Comment: Not only confuse but also break everything referencing string after that point.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for more than a True/False, you'd be best suited to use the re module, like:

```
import re
search="please help me out"
fullstring="please help me out so that I could solve this"
s = re.search(search,fullstring)
print(s.group())
```

`s.group()` will return the string "please help me out".

Comment: Good tip about regular expression searches.

Comment: on a lighter note. if you are trying to solve something with regular expression, you are trying to solve two problems.

Answer (score 9):

People mentioned `string.find()`, `string.index()`, and `string.indexOf()` in the comments, and I summarize them here (according to the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)):

First of all there is not a `string.indexOf()` method. The link posted by Deviljho shows this is a JavaScript function.

Second the `string.find()` and `string.index()` actually return the index of a substring. The only difference is how they handle the substring not found situation: `string.find()` returns `-1` while `string.index()` raises an `ValueError`.

Answer (score 9):

Thought I would add this in case you are looking at how to do this for a technical interview where they don't want you to use Python's built-in function `in` or `find`, which is horrible, but does happen:

```
string = "Samantha"
word = "man"

def find_sub_string(word, string):
  len_word = len(word)  #returns 3

  for i in range(len(string)-1):
    if string[i: i + len_word] == word:
  return True

  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Nice example, but your identation is incorrect. And to speed things up I'd check `if len(substring) > len(string) return False` also the loop range should better be `range(len(string)-len(substring))` because you won't find a three letter word in the last two letters of the string. (Saves a few iterations).

Answer (score 5):

You can also try `find()` method. It determines if string `str` occurs in string, or in a substring of string.

```
str1 = "please help me out so that I could solve this"
str2 = "please help me out"
        
if (str1.find(str2)>=0):
  print("True")
else:
  print ("False")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [7]: substring = "please help me out"

In [8]: string = "please help me out so that I could solve this"

In [9]: substring in string
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_substring():
    s = 'bobobnnnnbobmmmbosssbob'
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+3] == 'bob':
            cnt += 1
    print 'bob found: ' + str(cnt)
    return cnt

def main():
    print(find_substring())

main()
```

Comment: find substring 'bob' in a given string.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use this method

```
if substring in string:
    print(string + '\n Yes located at:'.format(string.find(substring)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Instead Of using find(), One of the easy way is the Use of  'in' as above.

if 'substring' is present in 'str' then if part will execute otherwise else part will execute.