# Match everything inside multiple instances of a tag in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Sample string:

```
str = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)"
```

Result should be a list:

```
res = [John, Mary]
```

I should really have learned regex by now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361253/python-how-to-find-a-substring-in-another-string or you should really have learned to google ;)

Comment: Duely noted! :) Thanks!

Comment: -1 for no attempt shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with (something like) XML. Use [a parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

str = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)"

doc = ET.fromstring("<root>" + str + "</root>")
result = [x.text for x in doc.findall(".//sec")]

# >>> ['John', 'Mary']
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see this! This also seems to work very nicely! Thanks!

Comment: Not only does it work, it's also much more failure-resistant and a lot more flexible.

Comment: I recognize that! I have changed the accepted answer.

Comment: I gave your question an up-vote to counter the down-votes, but for next time please show some effort of your own. This is generally received favorably around StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
str = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)"
ext = re.findall(r'<sec>(\S+?)</sec>', str)
```

This will return `['John', 'Mary']`

`\S` - represents match any non-whitespace character.

`+?` - represents repeat a character one or more time(non-greedy).

`()` - represents extract everything that is inside of these parenthesis.

Comment: Note that parsing `xml` format with `re` is highly error-prone. You should use libraries such as `xml` or `lxml` instead. And it's unlikely that OP wanted to search for only 4-letter strings.