# How to stop the while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Newbie in programming and need something like this but it doesn't stop the while condition even after entering a string starting with '0x', and it keeps calling the function.I tired putting 'break' instead of increasing i value, still didn't work. Any one knows why?

```
i = 1
while i < 2:
    call_fun1()
    if hx =='0x':
        i+=1
```

Comment: What is `hx`? If it never equals the string `0x` your loop will never end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code will run into an ***infinite loop*** only when the while condition

```
while i < 2:
```

always turns out to be **`true`**. This will happen when the code section that is changing the value of `i`, i.e.

```
i+=1
```

is ***never executed***. This will happen when the `if` condition

```
if hx =='0x':
```

always turns out to be **`false`**.

So check why

```
if hx =='0x':
```

is always evaluated to `false`. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Rewrite the if condition as `if hx.startswith('0x')`.

Comment: Also, you have not shown how `hx` is assigned values. Since the variable part in expression `if hx =='0x':` is `hx`, you also need to make sure that `hx` is updated somewhere inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

With `if hx =='0x'`, you are checking if `hx` **equals** `"0x"`, not if it **starts** with it. You need to find a 'substring'. Check this question: [Examples for string find in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674764/examples-for-string-find-in-python)

Because of this, `i` is never incremented and therefore the loop will continue indefinitely.