# Unique phrase in the source code of an HTML page in Python3

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get `Python3` to display a certain phrase from an `HTML document`. For example, I'll be using the search engine https://duckduckgo.com .

I'd like the code to do  `key search` for `var error=document.getElementById;` and get it to display what in the parenthesis are, in this case, it would be "error_homepage". Any help would be appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
u = input ('Please enter URL: ')
x = urllib.request.urlopen(u)
print(x.read())
```

Comment: To do that you need an html parser like `beautifulsoup`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples for string find in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674764/examples-for-string-find-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read the website of interest, as you suggested, using `urllib.request`, and use regular expressions to search the retrieved HTML/JS/... code:

```
import re
import urllib.request

# the URL that data is read from
url = "http://..."

# the regex pattern for extracting element IDs
pattern = r"var error = document.getElementById\(['\"](?P<element_id>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)['\"]\);"

# fetch HTML code
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    html = f.read().decode("utf8")

# extract element IDs
for m in re.findall(pattern, html):
    print(m)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to try that out when I get the chance.